# parse deploy stopped working - issues "dial tcp: lookup api.parse.com: no such host" error

Tags: parse-platform

Today when I went to deploy to parse I got the error message below. It was working up until today, and it happens in any directory where I try to use parse. I reinstalled the command line tool but this didn't help. Any ideas as to what is going on and how I can get it to work again?

dial tcp: lookup api.parse.com: no such host
/home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/main.go:143        checkIfSupported
/home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/main.go:101        main
/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.4.2.linux.amd64/src/runtime/proc.go:72       main
/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.4.2.linux.amd64/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2233 goexit

Comment: what version of parse?  get newer and retry https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli

Comment: As I stated in the original question, I reinstalled the command line tool and that did not help...

Comment: is that host (api.parse.com) reachable on your host dns?   dig it or ping it. restart dns daemon on host

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

I can dig it successfully, but it does not ping.

I cleared the dns cache and rebooted, (which should restart the dns server???) to no avail.

I recently updated the java version to the latest available for the Mac. Perhaps that introduced the issue?

And as far as I can tell, it is parse and only parse that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

GOT THIS TO WORK!

go version 1.4.2 is the problem. Use homebrew to "brew install go" to get go version 1.5.3. then install parse-cli with:

'go get -t github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli'

now use 'parse-cli deploy' instead of 'parse deploy'

EDIT: In case you haven't set them:

export GOPATH=$HOME/golang
export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec

Comment: I then found it helpful to override my old parse CLI with this one via a soft-link or alias

Comment: Also these references to homebrew are for OSX

Comment: whenever i attempt a 'parse-cli' command, it says there no such command. should i be calling these commands from within a directory of go, or?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this same issue just by running the install:

```
curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash
```